# Showing that the sum of the reciprocals of primes less than $y$ is greater than $\log \log y -1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I am studying number theory using the book "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" by Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery. There is a part in the book where they prove that the sum of the reciprocals of primes that are less than or equal to a given number $y$ is greater than $\log \log y -1$. That is,

$\displaystyle \sum_{p \leq y} \frac{1}{p} > \log \log y - 1. \tag*{}$

I don't understand the following part of the proof:

"Let $y\geq 2$ be given, and let $\mathscr{N}$ denote the set of all positive integers $n$ that are composed entirely of primes $p$ not exceeding $y$. Since there are only finitely many primes $p \leq y$, and since the terms of an absolutely convergent infinite series may be arbitrarily rearranged, we see that

$\displaystyle \prod_{p \leq y} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^3} + \dots \right) = \sum_{n \in \mathscr{N}} \frac{1}{n}. \tag{1}"$

I don't understand how we get from the left-hand side to the right-hand side. The sum inside the product is the geometric series, so we can rewrite the LHS as

$\displaystyle \prod_{p \leq y} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{p}\right)^j = \prod_{p \leq y} \frac{p}{p-1}.\tag*{}$

I am stuck here. I don't know how we get to $\sum_{n\in \mathscr{N}} \frac{1}{n}$. I tried looking it up, but I mostly found things about the Riemann zeta function which confused me even more.

Any helps that show me the steps to get from the LHS to the RHS of the equation (**1**) would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that any number in $\mathscr N$ can be uniquely factored into primes $\le$ y by the definition of $\mathscr N$ and the unique factorization theorem. So every term in the sum can be written by taking one term from each term of the product and multiplying them in a unique way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each number $n\in\mathscr{N}$ is of the form $2^a3^b5^c7^d\cdots q^z$ for some non-negative integers $a,b,c,d,\ldots,z$, where $q$ denotes the largest prime less than or equal to $y$. It follows that

$$\sum_{n\in\mathscr{N}}{1\over n}=\sum_{a=0}^\infty\sum_{b=0}^\infty\cdots\sum_{z=0}^\infty{1\over2^a3^b\cdots q^z}=\left(\sum_{a=0}^\infty{1\over2^a} \right)\left(\sum_{b=0}^\infty{1\over3^b} \right)\cdots\left(\sum_{z=0}^\infty{1\over q^z} \right)\\=\prod_{p\le y}\left(1+{1\over p}+{1\over p^2}+\cdots\right)$$